# How can I share funny things that I found in the SE network?

Tags: discussion, fun, sharing

I've found something funny and interesting on Stack Exchange and I want to share it with others. Things I've considered so far:

- ✖ Post on Meta or its Per-site Meta. Obviously OT.
- ❓ Share in my personal social media. A serious downside is the fact that few of them browse SE.
- ❓ Share on a corresponding forum. It's very likely to be badly-received for being off-topic there.

Are there any ideas that the MSE community has?

Comment: How about SE chat?

Comment: As pointed by @S.L.Barth use chat. also you can use your profile section

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see two options:

- Show it on your profile. You're allowed to put all kinds of random stuff there. I've always liked this line in Bhargav Rao's [profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4099593/bhargav-rao):

  > Remember that [this user](/users/current) rocks and is the best person on earth.
- Share it in a chatroom you frequent, if you know the (informal) code of conduct allows this and there are no other pressing matters to discuss. E.g. people post all kind of funny things in the [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta).
- @rene mentions [this Tumblr page](http://gemsfromstackexchange.tumblr.com/) which I've seen once before and is quite funny. It's some kind of social media without the downside you mentioned; you know the audience is SE-minded.

Comment: you can point to won't's profile. He have a good set of fun stuff in his profile. https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1228/wont

Comment: @i-- thanks, but I doubt that's the kind of things iBug is looking for; it's just random fun stuff, unrelated to SE (except the Best practice zombies link maybe). The funniest thing (to me) is that he's called 'Will' on SO and 'Won't' on MSE ...

Comment: How about http://gemsfromstackexchange.tumblr.com/

Comment: The "this user rocks" link freaked me out until I got it.

Comment: Awww... somebody noticed. :)

Answer (score 2):

I fail to see how the fact that your social network doesn't (yet) use SE means you can't share funny things with them. I shared a question I found hilarious: [How do we know Humpty Dumpty was an egg?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/how-do-we-know-humpty-dumpty-was-an-egg) and among other things earned a gold badge for it. The [tweet](https://twitter.com/gregcons/status/840984456672530432) was retweeted by both Joel and Jeff, and I gained quite a few followers from it. I expect a few of the people who read the tweet became SE users as a result of it. Certainly many people enjoyed it. Various Facebook friends went on to share links directly to the question.

If it's only funny if you know all the injokes of the site, then perhaps sharing it outside the site isn't needed. But that's rarely the case.